# How to avoid html codes in wcf xml response?

Tags: wcf

i wrote one method for getting details.in rest client getting response like this.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;Meetings&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Meeting&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Id&gt;1&lt;/Id&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Name&gt;Meeting1&lt;/Name&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Place&gt;SR Nagar&lt;/Place&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Time&gt;12/4/12 12:30pm&lt;/Time&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/Meeting&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Meeting&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Id&gt;2&lt;/Id&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Name&gt;Meeting2&lt;/Name&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Place&gt;Begumpet&lt;/Place&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Time&gt;12/4/12 1:00pm&lt;/Time&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/Meeting&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/Meetings&gt;&#xD;
</string>
```

in rendered html getting proper.

```
<Meetings> <Meeting> <Id>1</Id> <Name>Meeting1</Name> <Place>SR Nagar</Place> <Time>12/4/12 12:30pm</Time> </Meeting> <Meeting> <Id>2</Id> <Name>Meeting2</Name> <Place>Begumpet</Place> <Time>12/4/12 1:00pm</Time> </Meeting> </Meetings>
```

How to handle it in code in wcf to avoid <

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service operation returns `string` and you are writing XML to that string. It will always look like that and browser shows it correctly only because it hides `string` tag and unescapes the content.

To return real XML you must not use `string` as return value. Try to use for example `XElement`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `[OperationContract]` method, instead of returning a string, return an array of `Meeting` objects. The `Meeting` class should contain the properties you'd like to return:

```
[DataContract]
public class Meeting
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Place { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

If you're using .NET 4.0 and up, the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes are not required.